# Local storage in chrome not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

OPTIONS PAGE

```
// gets button from page
var checkButton = document.getElementById('saveCheck');

// initiates check fucntion when clicked 
checkButton.addEventListener('click', check);

// starts when youtube setting is saved
function check() {
  console.log('Check starts');

  //initiates if checkbox is checked
  if (check.checked) {
    console.log('its checked');
    localStorage.youtube = 1;
  } else {
    console.log('it isnt checked');
    localStorage.youtube = 0;
  }
}

console.log(localStorage.youtube);
```

This parts works perfectly, but when I try accessing the data stored in the local storage through my background.js page of my extension, it doesn't returns null for the values

BACKGROUND.JS

```
var ytcheck = localStorage.getItem('youtube');
console.log(ytcheck);
```

Comment: You can try `ytcheck = localStorage["youtube"];` and reverse for setting.

Comment: Verify if it is setting localStorage in Chrome developer tools under the resource tab.

Comment: Yes, the local storage is setting as seen in the resource tab

Comment: Well then localStorage is working. Could anything else be getting in the way? is there any other code?

Comment: Are you running this file locally?  In Chrome, `localStorage` is blocked for local files and only works with those served from a webserver.

Comment: Yes, I'm running this locally. Anyway I could get around this without having to pack my extension?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem, I have an unpacked extension loaded in Chrome and its options page and background page are sharing localStorage. However, why are you not using `chrome.storage` instead?

Comment: @zig-mandel's idea might be valid if you have a weird manifest. Can you post your manifest file?